# ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: pymysql

I am trying to create an SQL table using python and  PYMySQL package,  but it keeps showing errors. my code is here:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host = 'database-1.czswegfdjhpn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port = int(3306),
    user = 'admin',
    password = '',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print('connected succussfully')
cursor.execute('create database covid_19')
cursor.execute('use covid_19')

#creat table
sql_query = '''
     CREATE TABLE covid_19_world_cases_deaths_testing (
    iso_code varchar, continent varchar, location varchar, date varchar, total_cases float, \ 
    new_cases float, new_cases_smoothed float, total_deaths float, new_deaths float,\
    new_deaths_smoothed float, total_cases_per_million float, new_cases_per_million float,\
    new_cases_smoothed_per_million float, total_deaths_per_million float, new_deaths_per_million float,\
    new_deaths_smoothed_per_million float, reproduction_rate float, icu_patients float,\ 
    icu_patients_per_million float, hosp_patients float, hosp_patients_per_million float,\
    weekly_icu_admissions float, weekly_icu_admissions_per_million float, weekly_hosp_admissions float,\
    weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million float, total_tests float, new_tests float, total_tests_per_thousand float,\ 
    new_tests_per_thousand float, new_tests_smoothed float, new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand float, positive_rate float,\ 
    tests_per_case float, tests_units varchar, total_vaccinations float, people_vaccinated float, people_fully_vaccinated float,\ 
    total_boosters float, new_vaccinations float, new_vaccinations_smoothed float, total_vaccinations_per_hundred float,\ 
    people_vaccinated_per_hundred float, people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred float, total_boosters_per_hundred float,\
    new_vaccinations_smoothed_per_million float, new_people_vaccinated_smoothed float, new_people_vaccinated_smoothed_per_hundred float,\
    stringency_index float, population float, population_density float, median_age float, aged_65_older float,\ 
    aged_70_older float, gdp_per_capita float, extreme_poverty float, cardiovasc_death_rate float, diabetes_prevalence float,\
    female_smokers float, male_smokers float, handwashing_facilities float, hospital_beds_per_thousand float, life_expectancy float,\
    human_development_index float, excess_mortality_cumulative_absolute float, excess_mortality_cumulative float, excess_mortality float,\ 
    excess_mortality_cumulative_per_million float
)
'''

cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

**ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', continent varchar, location varchar, date varchar, total_cases float, \ \n    n' at line 2")**

Comment: You can use one of the "online sql syntax checker" pages to see what is wrong with your syntax.  If the checker does not point to an obvious spot, copy the full table command and start cutting away some of the fields until you find the wrong part.

Comment: Date is a data type in mySql, you cannot name a column as 'date'. Rename it and try. Also, since you used triple quotes for multiline, no need for backslash, remove them.